# How to click on a widget which is *below*?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have a set of images, created on a canvas by `create_image`.
Each one had its on `tag_bind` to both `<Button-1>` and `<Double-1>` - everything working well.

But it failed once I decided to show the currently selected image by overimposing - again by `create_image` - a semitransparent image (*selectedicon*) which allows to see which image is selected. Using `<Button-1>` on any image moves *selectedicon* above it.
Now that *selectedicon* is above, it prevents the `<Double-1>` to activate on the image below.

Is it possible to make the widget reactive even if it is below another widget?

Comment: I had a similar problem and was unable to find such a method.  Instead I bound the whole canvas to Button-1 and used the function `find_overlapping` to get all the objects at that point.   The arguments I used to `find_overlapping` were x0 and x1 both set to mouse x, y0 and y1 set to mouse y.  That's a rectangle with no area - weird but it worked.

Comment: that sounds strange! I'll have to try it...

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Your description isn't enough for us to understand the problem.